# Как сделать чтобы только люди, с определёнными ролями могли использовать команду

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

Мне нужно как-то сделать так, чтобы только люди, с определёнными ролями могли использовать админ-команды.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Обратитесь к документации. [Checks](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html#checks)

```
def is_guild_owner():
    def predicate(ctx):
        return ctx.guild is not None and ctx.guild.owner_id == ctx.author.id
    return commands.check(predicate)

@bot.command()
@commands.check_any(commands.is_owner(), is_guild_owner())
async def only_for_owners(ctx):
    await ctx.send('Hello mister owner!')
```

Конкретно в вашем случае, что-то типа этого:

```
@bot.command()
@commands.has_any_role('Library Devs', 'Moderators', 492212595072434186)
async def cool(ctx):
    await ctx.send('You are cool indeed')
```

Comment: @Юзер Нет, это просто примеры. Без кода не очень понятно. Скиньте код, иначе не угадаю что не так